# return difference of multiple columns as a vector separated by ","

Tags: r, dataframe, difference

I have a dataset in the following format. `V1`, `V2` & `V3` are populated with date (within a month). I want to populate my output column, a vector of difference of columns separated by ","

```
ID  V1   V2  V3    #Output Column
1   08   21  26         13,5
2   11   13  19          2,6 
3   13   17  21          4,4
4   06   11  16          5,5
5   07   09  11          2,2
6   02   05  09          3,4
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You will probably get better answers if you both clarify what you want with full question and show some sample code

Comment: @merlin2011 - df$V2 - df$V1 is what i have tried so far. I have 34 columns and i need difference of each column to the preceding column separated by ","

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution without the need to type every column combination:

```
dat$output <- apply(t(apply(dat[,-1], 1, diff)), 1, paste, collapse = ",")
```

which gives:

```
> dat
  ID V1 V2 V3 output
1  1  8 21 26   13,5
2  2 11 13 19    2,6
3  3 13 17 21    4,4
4  4  6 11 16    5,5
5  5  7  9 11    2,2
6  6  2  5  9    3,4
```

Explanation:

With `t(apply(dat[,-1], 1, diff))` you create a matrix of the differences between the columns. By wrapping that in another `apply` call (`apply(x, 1, paste, collapse = ",")`) and assign that to the output column. With `dat[,-1]` you exclude the `id` column from the difference calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
df$ouput <- paste(df$V2 - df$V1,",",df$V3 - df$V2, sep = "")
```

Considering `df` as your data frame

Comment: I have 34 columns (V1 - V34). Is there any other way to reduce the long version of typing each column name with their preceding column name?

Comment: @Riza See Jaap's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `diff`

Some data:

```
> V1 = c(8,11,13,6,7, 2)
> V2 = c(21,13,17,11,09,05)
> V3 = c(26,21,16,11, 9)
```

Solution:

```
rbind(diff(rbind(V1,V2)), diff(rbind(V2,V3)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code.
Suppose Data has been stored in table name as TEMP_TABLE.
1. Please run below query.
2. select concat( concat(V1-V2, ','), V2-V3) from TEMP_TABLE 
3. Required data will come.

Thanks

Comment: This is select statement for DB

Comment: This is an R question